# How to match a pattern in a string

Tags: php, regex

String

```
$x= "SDGH <fn>xyz("|",YAG);</fn> is right ";
$code = ?? ;
eval($code);
```

I have to get the code which is inside the tag and execute it .

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best way to achieve this would probably be using regular expressions. If you want to learn more about regex, check out [this tutorial](http://regexone.com/).

```
if(preg_match("/<fn>(.*)<\/fn>/",$x, $matches))
    $code = $matches[1];
```

This code matches everything inbetween `<fn>` and `</fn>`. Bear in mind that using `eval` is always dangerous whenever user input is involved. In that case, you'd need to make sure that only certain code is allowed to execute.

Comment: explanation would be great

Comment: `preg_match("!<fn>(.*)</fn>!",$x,$fn);`  even this works . Thanks for your answer will accept it in 6 minutes

Comment: @treegarden How can I show the complete string that was passed with the result of the <fn></n> tag in it  ? .

Comment: You could do something like: `echo str_replace($matches[0], eval($matches[1]), $x);`. That replaces the matched part with the evaluation

Answer (score 0):

You don't need regex, you can also get it with string function.

```
$input = 'SDGH <fn>xyz("|",YAG);</fn> is right';
$output = substr($input, strpos($input, '<fn>') + 4);
$output = substr($output, 0, strpos($output, '</fn>'));
echo $output;
```

There're many ways to get this result, you can use regex, string functions, even explode

Comment: bro just one more query , If I have to show the out put as the string string like this .... `SDGH SomName is right`. Here some name is the returned value of the function that is being passed between the tag . How can I achive it  ?